# "Is that an old picture?" Vs "Is that picture old?"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

> Is that an old picture?
>
> Is that picture old?

Do both sentences mean the exact same thing?

The world "old" is an adjective and I've been told that you generally use adjective + noun.

Why does the second version work?

Comment: An old picture means the picture was taken a long time ago. But a picture isn`t a living thing. Is that an old picture sounds fine, but is that picture old sounds odd to me.

Comment: Both sound fine to me. (AmE)

Answer (score 1):

Both are essentially the same.

Regarding the second one.  Consider the sentence:  *"That picture is old."*  It's a typical subject complement sentence (adjective, noun, or pronoun following a "linking" verb.)  Now, if you make this an interrogative sentence (by adding "is" and a question mark) you have the sentence *"Is that picture old?"*

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question first: In "Is that picture old?", "old" isn't modifying "picture"--that is, it isn't being used attributively. It's being used predicatively, as part of the predicate. It's the question form of the statement "That picture is old," in which the "is" moves to the beginning of the sentence.

You're correct that when the adjective is used *attributively*, it precedes the noun, as in the question "Is that an old picture?" or its declarative form "That is an old picture."

Returning to the first question: If you ask "Is that picture old?", you're *implying* that you know it's a picture; you're asking only *whether* the picture is old. Therefore, if the answer isn't yes, negative answers you might expect would be limited to "No, that picture is new" or "No, it was just taken a couple of years ago".

However, if you ask "Is that an old picture?", you *could* mean that you aren't even sure it's a picture. Possible negative answers could be either of the two I listed above, but they could also be, "No, it isn't a picture at all" or "No, it's a new tablet" or "No, it's an empty frame".

*Practically speaking*, if it *is* a picture, and you know that it is, and it's obvious to the listener that you know that it is, so that there is *no* question about whether it's a *picture*, *then* both questions would be understood to be asking only about the "old" part.